# Setting the value of a jQuery Multiselect DropDownList to "All" on page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind, jquery-ui-multiselect

On my page, I have a series of jQuery DropDowns with this coding on the ASP page (some are slightly altered, but that's not relevant):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(function () {
    jQuery("#UCStyle1 select").multiselect({
        header: true,
        height: 175,
        minWidth: 240,
        size: 3,
        classes: '',
        checkAllText: 'Check all',
        uncheckAllText: 'Uncheck all',
        noneSelectedText: '0 Selected',
        selectedText: '# selected',
        selectedList: 0,
        show: null,
        hide: null,
        autoOpen: false,
        multiple: true,
        position: {},
        appendTo: "body"
    });
    });
```

In the code-behind, if I want to select a single value in one of these dropdowns on page load, I can do it this way:

```
sCountry.SelectedValue = "USA";
```

How do I do it if I want to select **all** the values in the multiselect?

Comment: Which jQuery MultiSelect widget are you using?

Comment: jQuery MultiSelect UI Widget 1.13  * Copyright (c) 2012 Eric Hynds

Comment: Could you able to catch the posted value in code behind? I'm just curious whether it works in ASP.Net Web Form.

Answer (score 0):

From the source code for the widget, it would seem as though you'd add this at page load.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $("#UCStyle1 select").multiselect({
            header: true,
            height: 175,
            minWidth: 240,
            size: 3,
            classes: '',
            checkAllText: 'Check all',
            uncheckAllText: 'Uncheck all',
            noneSelectedText: '0 Selected',
            selectedText: '# selected',
            selectedList: 0,
            show: null,
            hide: null,
            autoOpen: false,
            multiple: true,
            position: {},
            appendTo: "body"
        }).checkAll();
    });
});
```

Comment: I was looking to do it in the code-behind (C#) rather than jQuery

Comment: Are you populating via `@Html.DropDownFor(...)`?

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered one solution (in case anyone stops by looking for an answer):

```
foreach (ListItem li in sCountry.Items)
{
    li.Selected = true;
}
```

Still hoping there's something a little more elegant/a one-line way to do this, but for now this works.